# Need help for Drupal 7 Ajax Add more form elements

Tags: 7, ajax

```
    $form['feedbackmarkup']['feedback']['num_domains'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => 1,
);  
       $num = isset($form_state['values']['num_domains']) ? $form_state['values']['num_domains'] : 1;
     for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
    $form['feedbackmarkup']['feedback']['fname_'.$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 12,
        '#required' => true,
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );
    }
       $form['add_more'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Add More'),
        '#href' => '',
        '#ajax' => array(
           'callback' => 'for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
    $form['feedbackmarkup']['feedback']['fname_'.$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#size' => 12,
        '#required' => true,
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );',
           'wrapper' => 'feedback_replace',
         ),
       );
```

and In my Ajax callback function

```
  function ajax_example_simplest_callback($form, $form_state) {
         $test = isset($form_state['values']['num_domains']) ? $form_state['values']['num_domains']+1 : 1;
        $form['feedbackmarkup']['feedback']['num_domains']['#value'] = $test;
       drupal_set_message(print_r($form_state['values'],true)); //It is printing form_state with values but not adding my fields above in for loop
        return $form['feedbackmarkup']['feedback'];
}
```

Comment: in my ajax_example_simplest_callback function it is printing form_state with increase value in num_domains but in above code $form_state does not change or i think form is not rendring.. i print the form_state but it doesn't rendring...

Comment: Is it necessary to add: **$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;** in your callback function ?

Comment: @dskanth i added the solution in answer and forgot to mark it. sry.

Comment: I have a similar question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70268/drupal-7-add-fields-to-form-dynamically-with-ajax-and-retrieve-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not adding my field because `#required` is set to `true`. Now I removed it, and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you passing `$form_state` by reference, like

```
function module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: ya it is written like this... 
`function custom_add_feedback_provider($form, &$form_state, $sess_id) {
}`

Comment: $sess_id is the argument..

Comment: hey i did it. just need to change method of ajax to 'append' :D